# Celery: When and where to use the return value of a .delay() running @task to update DB?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, asynchronous, celery

I am building a Django app with Celery.

I have a `@task` which I fire with `.delay()`.

Once the task is complete, I need to use the return value (a string) to update my Postgres DB.

I am not sure where should I put the DB update code?

Do I do:

a)

```
return_value = my_task.delay(..)
(ORM - DB update code)
```

b)

```
my_task.delay(..) # <-- Task updates the DB.
```

Which is the Pythonic correct way here?

Comment: You could try chaining your tasks, so they are run one after another.  That's probably the most pythonic.  "More complex" is frequently not better.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use the second approach since delay method exits right away without waiting for your task to finish. And the return_value variable will be [AsyncResult](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html#celery.result.AsyncResult%20AsyncResult) instance, not the value you wanted to return from my_task. So if you want to update the DB once the task is complete, do it inside the task.

Alternatively you could use on_success handler of the Task class:

```
class MyTask(Task):

    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # your task execution code

    def on_success(self, retval, task_id, args, kwargs):
        # put the retval into the DB
```

Comment: Hi @isobolev. I am working on this right now, thanks! Can you confirm this is absolutely the way to go and it is Pythonic? Would there be a perhaps more complex but more Pythonic way? I'm new!

Comment: @Phil I added alternative solution to my answer.

Comment: upvoted, this works if you are updating the db, how do I update the instance variable in the class from where I fired delay() if I had a class A